# Using Visual Studio Web Developer for building a regular html website?

Tags: html, visual-studio, web, ide

I was wondering if it is a good idea to use VS as an IDE to build a regular HTML website with CSS and Javascript without using ASP.NET. It's mostly because I'm so used to VS and the conveniences it affords.

I was planning on building a "master project" using aspx files and create separate html files once it is ready deploy. The html files would be generated from what the browser in my test environment receives.

I have tried Aptana Studio and Dreamweaver, and they are quite good, but I wanna centralize as much as possible with a single IDE. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, why not? I'd build an ASP.Net MVC project...excellent [samples/scaffolding](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples), and minimal code required if you want static HTML. In return, you get a clean project structure, "pretty" URLs, separation of concerns, and extensibility for the future (in case you ever *do* want server-side functionality).

Comment: While I would never build a pure HTML site nowadays (There's always _some_ feature that needs a server), if I were to do so, I'd use VS for the excellent intellisense, previews, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think choosing an IDE for a project completely depends on the developer and how he/she is familiar with it.

For your case i think you should use vs, because first you are familiar with it (and probably know the hotkeys), second vs is the best IDE in my opinion among all other IDE's available for html for anyone who wants to use its intellisense as it would suggest more suggestions than any other ide if you are using vs 2012 for microsoft build an extremely good ide for html and work on it in 2012 version. I mysqlf usually work with notepad++ , but in your situation i suggest vs 2012.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to look for good plugins for web development in VS2012 then.